# Can a company take money from a Debit Card at a Later Date?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, online-payment, online

I have booked an online service from a web site which only asked me for the **Debit** / Credit Card Info (**Visa Electron**) to reserve the service (Only save my Card details are saved, no deductions are made until I receive the service).

Unfortunately I decided that I didn't want that service but forgot to cancel it, however, there is not enough money in my debit card on the day I would have received the service. They have not deducted the money, and wouldn't have been able to if they had tried.

If I add money to my debit card account can they deduct any money later? I am scared so am still keeping a very limited amount of  money in the account.

Comment: It depends, quite a few times hotel put a policy of "definitely charge", to encourage right bookings and cancellations. There are times when inspite of policy the hotel will not charge for bookings if not checked in or stayed. But as pointed out Vicky if they do decide to charge, they will ... and your obligation does not end by not keeping enough balance.

Answer (score 8):

Whether or not you have money in your account will not necessarily stop them withdrawing the money, and it certainly won't stop them attempting to withdraw the money. There are two possible scenarios when they attempt to withdraw the money (as they surely will):

1. The bank **refuses** the withdrawal: you still owe them the money, you may also owe additional late payment fees, the bank may also charge you for a refused payment. If you continue to refuse to pay they could sue you for it.
2. The bank **permits** the withdrawal: they get their money, you may then owe fees or charges to the bank for the (unauthorised?) overdraft.

I think you are just lucky they haven't attempted the withdrawal yet. Put the necessary money into your account now if you possibly can, and consider this a slightly expensive lesson learned about following the Ts and Cs when cancelling services.